# Changing Constraints and Primitive Structure of Database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, database-schema, multiple-databases

How is the database supposed to handle requirement of implementing new organizational policies. Which may make obsolete previously valid constraint and can demand new constraints for data in time to come.

If we change such constraint and critical structures as per new policies how old policy data will hold its integrity?

So what is best practice? Separate databases with every new policy implementation. And make a datawarehouse on top?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for some kind of "temporal" constraints. No database system I'm aware of supports such a construct. I can see things quickly getting messy as soon as an older row is updated once a new version of a constraint has been applied (which version of the constraint is applied, old or new? What if a constraint applies to multiple columns and *some* of those columns are subject to update? Whole can of worms here)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately SQL DBMSs are not very good at implementing data integrity rules. ISO Standard SQL has the concept of an ASSERTION constraint for example, but SQL Server and most other DBMSs do not implement it. Constraints between tables are seriously limited because of standard SQL's lack of support for multiple assignment. SQL normally only allows one table to be updated at a time which makes it difficult to implement inclusion dependencies and join dependencies.

These limitations mean that business rules tend to get implemented either in procedural code (stored procedures) or outside the database altogether: using data quality tools, rules engines or exception reporting. Such tools tend to have better support for version control when the rules change over time.

Comment: Well. They do support constraints. Yes most what limited than liking. But the question is about how to accommodate changing constraints. Let suppose there was a age bearer in db. That employees of age above 18 can be enrolled just. And we applied the constraints and get thousand of valid age records. Later there come directive that now age limit is increased to 21 for next onward employees. Now if we update the check value. The previous records will not stand valid. Whereas as per policy they are valid as they are previous policy records. How to deal with that situation.

Comment: In that particular case:
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CHECK (
AgeInYears(birthdate, startdate) > 21
OR (AgeInYears(birthdate, startdate) > 18 AND startdate <'2018-01-01'));
this assumes you have defined an AgeInYears function to calculate an employee's age.